# I want to display the badge number dynamically using javascript for bootstrap button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In CSS though I have given the badge number as `0`, dynamically it should be changed by jQuery/JavaScript. Following code I tried but that didn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload='preventDefault()'>
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default like-btn active" type="button" id="10">
    <span class="text">Alert</span>
    <span class="badge like-badge">0</span>
</button>
</div>
<script>
 preventDefault = function(){
 var btnText = $(this).find(".btn-text")       
 var badge = $(this).find(".like-badge")
 var count = parseInt(badge.text());
 if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        btnText.text("Like");
        badge.text(2);
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
  else {
        btnCaption.text("Liked");
        badge.text(count + 1);
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please elaborate on what error you are getting and what you've tried so far to fix it. Also, have a look at [this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

I have correct some code snippet..

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-default like-btn active" onclick="preventDefault()" type="button" id="10">
<span class="btn-text">Alert</span>
<span class="badge like-badge">0</span>
</button>
```

added `btn-text` for button text.

javascript corrections:

```
preventDefault = function(){
   var btn = $('.btn');
   var btnText = $(this).find(".btn-text")       
   var badge = $(".like-badge");
   var count = parseInt(badge.text());
   console.log(count);

   if (btn.hasClass('active')) {
      btnText.text("Like");
      badge.text(2);
      btn.removeClass('active');
   }else {
      btnText.text("Liked");
      badge.text(count + 1);
      btn.addClass('active');
   }
}
```

added `var btn = $('.btn');` for selecting button element.

called `btn` instead `$(this)` in `if` condition.

Hurray!! code works for me.
Please check if it satisfy you.

Comment: Thanks Mubin ..yeah it works when I tried to execute it from browser standalone.. actually I would have to implement this logic in sap crm webui platform.. which supports modern web logics I.e. JavaScript, jquery etc .. here the problem is the badge number remains same as defined in the css .. either the script is not working or it is not getting triggered .. can you or anybody tell me how can I trigger this script on initial load of the page without clicking or performing any actions I.e onClick etc . 
Thanks in advance 

Comment: @SouvikSaha the script runs when the page loads because you have put `onload='preventDefault()'` . `onload` runs the function.